# Jumper or resistor?

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, jumper

I have in my BOM (Bill of materials) the following component CR21- 000-T and in the datasheet of the component : [CR, CJ series](http://www.mouser.com/catalog/specsheets/cr05-32.pdf) is specified  CR21 series as 0805 resistor.
[image: CR21-000-T]

But the 000 is specified as a chip jumper
Blank = jumper chips.

Is this a resistor or a jumper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect it is a 0-ohm resistor (hence the "000"), which is often used as a jumper in all sorts of board layouts. It allows traces to be laid where they couldn't normally be laid due to another trace on the same layer.

Here is an example:

[image]

R2 is being used to jump over the trace connecting D1 to R1 (Signal 2) so that the trace between IC1 and C1 (Signal 1) doesn't have to be on another layer.

Comment: In your schematic, can the resistor R2 be configured 
(manually) as a jumper or is welded between R1 and D1 ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you referring the the *schematic* or to the *board layout*? The 0805 component is effectively a resistor, so you would have a footprint on your PCB for it. The resistor jumper would be soldered to that footprint. That's part of the layout process

Comment: @codo you are asking if its OPTIONAL or otherwise Removable, no. In this circuit, it's *soldered* on. The use of "jumper" simply means its normally used to jump over another trace, not as a removable/selectable part.

Comment: @Passerby thank you, yes this is excatly what i'm asking for.

Answer (score 4):

CR21-000-T is probably a mistype and should be a jumper CJ21-000-T.

In the excerpt from the datasheet you have given, you can also see that there should be a tolerance listed in the part number if it was a resistor. Because that is also missing from the number, I'd say it is just a 0805 jumper.

The exact part is also no longer available ([Mouser product page](http://www.mouser.de/search/ProductDetail.aspx?AVX%2FCJ21-000-T%2F&qs=JcrIDYvCK%252bl2%2Faoe85JPLA%3D%3D)), but I'd say you just can use any 0805 jumper out there as replacement.

---

Addition:

Based on the comments on @derstrom8 answer you were also wondering if this is a jumper like they are used on many boards to select features:

[image: common plastic jumper]

Basically: No, resistor jumpers are used like a normal resistor, so they are soldered onto the board and stay there. Commonly used to cross two signals on the same layer if other methods are not viable. For example in a single layer layout.

They can be used to select options, but typically not for an end user as it requires soldering. You can find this on some development boards though, like on the [STM Nucleo](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00105823.pdf#page=13) (the SB refers to Solder Bridge, in the [schematic](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00105823.pdf#page=58) they look a different to a normal jumper).

During manufacturing you can decide if you want to populate all of the resistor jumpers or not. You can use that information to, say select features or to identify a certain product if the board is used in multiple products.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly certain what question you are asking.

It is common practice to use a Zero-Ohm chip resistor as a jumper because it is a component that can be handled by the same machine that places all of the other similarly-sized components.

The marking on a Zero-Ohm chip jumper varies by manufacturer.  I've seen many different markings: blank, a single "0", a triple zero (000), a single black rectangle with no other marking.  I'm sure that there are other markings that I haven't yet seen.

Comment: I have seen a number of resistors that are simply a black rectangle with no marking. So just because it has no marking, don't assume it's a jumper. However, marking with zeros is a pretty unambiguous indication of a jumper.

Answer (score 0):

It's a zero-ohm resistor, which is also a jumper.

The word 'jumper' means a piece of metal that connects two points in a circuit.

Some examples of jumpers:

- Those 0.1" push-on jumpers that you use connecting pins on a header.
- A piece of wire soldered between two points.
- The cables you use to connect your car battery to somebody else's.
- An 0805 resistor package with metal inside of it instead of something resistive.